# Best way to fetch a PHP array and output the result with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach

I am trying to grab some text from a MyBB forum's exported messages. The file is a CSV file.

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) === FALSE) { 
    exit("Couldn't load CSV");
}

fgetcsv($handle);

$messages = array(); 
$i = 0;

while($data = fgetcsv($handle)){
    if(count($data) == 7){
        $messages[$i]['date'] = $data[0] + "," + $data[1]; 
        $messages[$i]['folder'] = $data[2];
        $messages[$i]['subject'] = $data[3]; 
        $messages[$i]['receiver'] = $data[4];   
        $messages[$i]['sender'] = $data[5]; 
        $messages[$i]['message'] = str_replace("\'", "'", $data[6]); 
    }else{
        $messages[$i]['date'] = $data[0]; 
        $messages[$i]['folder'] = $data[1];
        $messages[$i]['subject'] = $data[2]; 
        $messages[$i]['receiver'] = $data[3]; 
        $messages[$i]['sender'] = $data[4];     
        $messages[$i]['message'] = str_replace("\'", "'", $data[5]);  
    }
    $i++;
}
```

I gave each tr and th tag (th includes the name of the sender and tr includes the message) a class with a number. First message is 0, second is 1, third is 2 and so on. I load the message in PHP like this:

```
$messages[0]['message'])
```

Where 0 is the first message. I want it to be like when I click on first message, it loads the first. When I click the second, it loads the second message. You get the idea.

My jQuery is as following:

```
$("td, th").on("click", function() {
    var message = $(this).attr("class");
    $("#message").text("<?= preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $messages[0]['message']) ?>");
});
```

I use preg_replace to get it all into one line.

**Foreach loop**

```
<table>
foreach($messages as $i => $message) {
echo <<<EOL
        <tr>
            <th class="$i"> {$message['sender']} </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="$i"> {$message['message']} </td>
        </tr> 
EOL;
}
</table>
```

So to sum up: I want to display the message when I click the message in the table, but I am not sure what would be the best approach to do that.

Comment: You should load your messages using AJAX. Have a look at it : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I know how to make an AJAX request, but setting it up properly is where I have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td, th").on("click", function() {
    var messageId = $(this).attr("class");
    $.ajax({
       url: "test.php",
       type: "post",
       data: messageId,
       success: function(returnedVal){
           $("#result").html(returnedVal);
       },
       error:function(){
           $("#result").html('There is an error');
       }
   });      
});
```

returnedVal is the value returned by your test.php.
For example, you can return your message.
Then you display it in $("#result") or wherever you want :)

Comment: So I should make an extra PHP file with all my PHP stuff in it? Called test.php in this example.

Comment: If you follow this example, yes, you should create test.php, in which you'll get the messageId through POST.

Comment: So to grab the $_GET stuff, what do I put instead of the 0 then?     $messages[0]['message']

Comment: In your test.php, you'll return `$message[$messageId]['message']`. And to grab messageId, it's just `$messageId = $_POST['messageId'];`

Comment: What do I do with the $message[$messageId]['message'] ? Where should I put it? I put the $_POST stuff in the PHP file just after the loop, but I am not sure where to put the first stuff.